# How to find if we can construct a bi-partite graph with the information about the degree of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Say there are two sets X and Y,which denote the degree of vertices of the bi partite graph.
Say X = {2,2,1} and Y = {2,3},with this information about the degree of vertices,how to tell if we can construct a bi partite graph or not?

My approach:
I know that the sum of degree of vertices should be same,i.e sum of set X = 5 and
sum of elements in set Y = 5.
But are there other conditions?

Comment: Well, obviously no element of $Y$ can be greater than $|X|$ and vice versa.  Try proving it possible by induction on the sum of the vertex degrees.

Comment: Should probably also include the hypothesis that no vertex is of degree zero, as that can throw things off.  $X=Y=\{3,0,0\}$ clearly isn't possible despite satisfying the conditions stated so far.